# Activities and the manifest in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, default

I know there are plenty of questions about this but I just can't work out why my program keeps loading the wrong activity even though I've made the correct one the default in the manifest. Here's some code for you all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="swin.examples"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="swin.examples.TemperatureConvertor"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>        
        <activity android:name="swin.examples.FeetToCmConvertor"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="swin.examples.Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here's where I think the problem will be if it's not in the manifest:

```
package swin.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initializeUI();
    }

private void initializeUI()
{
    Button btnCm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFeet);
    btnCm.setOnClickListener(btnFeetListener);
    Button convertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTemp);
    convertButton.setOnClickListener(btnTempListener);

}

/** Handle convert button click */ 
private OnClickListener btnTempListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            convertButtonClicked();
    }
};

private OnClickListener btnFeetListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            btnCmClicked();
    }
};

private void btnCmClicked()
{
    // set the sender and the receiver of the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), swin.examples.FeetToCmConvertor.class);

    startActivity(intent); // transmit your intent

}

private void convertButtonClicked()
{
    // set the sender and the receiver of the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), swin.examples.TemperatureConvertor.class);

    startActivity(intent); // transmit your intent  
}
}
```

I can't work it out and I hope you can help me! Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: Code updated, but still doesn't work. If this helps, this is the log messages:

```
[2013-04-20 22:44:20 - CombinedConvertor] Success!
[2013-04-20 22:44:21 - CombinedConvertor] Starting activity swin.examples.TemperatureConvertor on device emulator-5554
[2013-04-20 22:44:23 - CombinedConvertor] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=swin.examples/.TemperatureConvertor }
```

Comment: which Activity is getting loaded instead of which Activity?

Comment: temperatureconverter instead of main

Comment: @dragnflier: Try cleaning your project and then running it again. I am commenting here so I don't end up hijacking _Egor's_ answer. Also, before you do, change the `android:name="swin.examples.Main"` to just `android:name=".Main"`.

Comment: @IceMAN: still no dice. Nothing's changed in the way it runs. It still loads temperature converter

Comment: @dragnflier: A couple of things. Is this your complete Manifest file and the code from the `Main` activity or have you skipped a few things from it to keep it relevant. And second, can your uninstall the app from the emulator, and republish again?

Comment: @IceMAN: Complete manifest, not complete main. I've tried to keep it relevant. I'll try uninstalling it again but you can see my frustration! EDIT: No luck. Still not working!

Comment: @dragnflier: It is a curious issue indeed. Post your `Main` code. Perhaps there could be something there.

Comment: @IceMAN: Added in question, hopefully you can find it because I can't!

Comment: @dragnflier: Curious er and curious er. It compiled and ran the Main activity in a test project I quickly created. The only thing I have different is this in the Manifest: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` And the Activity names are `.TemperatureConvertor`, `.FeetToCmConvertor` and  `.Main`

Comment: @IceMAN: that is odd. I'll try adding that. Maybe eclipse just hates me. EDIT: Yep, Eclipse hates me. I'll try a new project. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @dragnflier: any luck getting it to work?

Comment: @IceMAN: I remade the TemperatureConvertor java file and it works now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @dragnflier: No problem fella. I am glad you got it sorted out. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Proper `IntentFilter` for the main `Activity` is

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it still loads the temperatureconverter activity.

Comment: @dragnflier: Is there a reason why you would assign `<intent-filter>` to all your `Activities`? I ask because _Egor's_ answer is correct and will work for you. Try commenting out the other `<intent-filter>` **except** for the `swin.examples.Main` Activity.

Comment: @IceMAN:  Even when I take those intent filters away, it's still loading temperatureconverter. I see what you're saying, but it boggles me too! I don't understand why it's still not working. I've tried everything I can logically think of

Answer (score 0):

Weirdest bug ever. Worked for everyone else, just not me. Remade temperatureconverter activity and it works now. Thank you everyone for your help!